# Check LatLngBounds.Builder if null

Tags: java, android, android-maps-v2

This is mycode:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for(int x = firstVisibleItem; x < lastVisibleItem; x++){
    builder.include(temp.getPosition());
}
```

However this line throws an error (`java.lang.IllegalStateException: no included points`
:

```
double north = builder.build().northeast.latitude;
```

This is because the above loop didn't run at all so no points were included in the `builder`.

How can I check if the builder has at least one point?

I tried `builder.build()!=null` which throws the above error and `builder!=null` which is always True.

`try{}catch(IllegalStateException e){   }`  works. Is it stupid to ask a `!=null` way? Mico-management? Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a counter and use it to verify that you have at least one point.

```
int counter = 0;
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for(int x = firstVisibleItem; x < lastVisibleItem; x++){
    counter++;
    builder.include(temp.getPosition());
}
if (counter > 0) {
    //use a LatLngBounds.Builder to build the LatLngBounds object
}
```

Comment: Good point, thanks.  Event simpler: `if(firstVisibleItem< lastVisibleItem)`

Comment: Glad to be helpful... and yes, you are right... this could be done too.