# java.lang.IllegalStateException: no included points

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am trying to list all the places according to the query type specified by the user. The app will show the map with markers of the places that are returned from the API call.

```
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    static String itemSelected;
    PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result;
    static int clicked;
    CharSequence[] items = {"accounting", "airport", "amusement_park", "aquarium", "art_gallery","atm","bakery","bank","bar","beauty_salon","bicycle_store","book_store","bowling_alley","bus_station","cafe"};



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)

                .enableAutoManage(this,this)
                .build();

        final AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        ad.setTitle("Pick a place")
                .setSingleChoiceItems(items, 0, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d("Demo", "Selected :" + items[which]);
                        clicked = which;
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        itemSelected = String.valueOf(items[clicked]);
                        Log.d("demo",itemSelected);
                        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);
                    }
                })
                .setCancelable(false);

        AlertDialog alert = ad.create();

        ad.show();   
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case 100:
            {
                if(grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                {
                    result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceLikelihoodBuffer placeLikelihoods) {
                            Log.d("demo",placeLikelihoods.getStatus()+"");
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Permission denied by the user", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            // TODO: Consider calling

            MapsActivity.this.requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},100);
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }

        result= Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient,null);

        final PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> pbuff = Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient,null);

        pbuff.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceLikelihoodBuffer placeLikelihoods) {
                LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

                for(PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : placeLikelihoods){

                    if (placeLikelihood.getPlace().getPlaceTypes().contains(itemSelected)){

                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng()).title(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName().toString()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
                        builder.include(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng());
                    }
                    else{
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng()).title(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName().toString()));
                        builder.include(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng());
                    }
                }

                placeLikelihoods.release();
                LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                int padding = 10; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
                CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
                mMap.animateCamera(cu);

                //mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 10));
                // Remove listener to prevent position reset on camera move.
                //mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(null);

//                LatLngBounds.Builder bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
//                for (DataItem location : mUserLocations.keySet()) {
//                    bounds.include(new LatLng(
//                            Double.parseDouble(location.mData
//                                    .get("latitude")), Double
//                            .parseDouble(location.mData
//                                    .get("longitude"))));
//                }
//
//                LatLngBounds mapBounds;
//                for (DataItem location : result. ) {
//                    if (mapBounds==null) {
//                        LatLng point = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(location.pbuff.get("latitude")), Double.parseDouble(location.mData.get("longitude")))
//                        mapBounds =new LatLngBounds(point, point);
//                    } else {
//                        mapBounds = mapBounds.including(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(location.mData.get("latitude")), Double.parseDouble(location.mData.get("longitude"))));
//                    }
//                }
            }
        });

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
//        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
//        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
//        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

But the app crashes with the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: no included points
>                                                                                                 at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzaa.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                 at
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds$Builder.build(Unknown
>   Source).

I have tried various other links posted on SO, but nothing seems to work. Please help. This is my first question on SO, please let me know if I have done any mistakes.

Comment: Isn't getPlaceTypes() an array of integer, how are you comparing it with a string? also, there are constants defined for place types, you should map them to get the correct integer value when the user select the type from the list https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place not sure if it is the origin of the error but looked strange to me

Comment: [`IllegalStateException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html) states that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation. Based from this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667506/check-latlngbounds-builder-if-null), try to create a counter and use it to verify that you have at least one point.